# Does Acumatica has some notification about current status of records

Tags: acumatica

Let's say I develop processing screen in Acumatica. Each row has column Processed, Failed. Processing of each row takes 3 seconds. I have 1000 records. I want notify user via grid during run-time that either record was Processed or Failed. Is it possible to mark columns as processed/failed during execution of method, not after method execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have it show the green check or red x on each row if that is what you are referring to? I believe it will update as they rows are processed. (Ex: first 5 rows show green check, 6th row shows red x, and all others still processing...) the Inventory release process will do this (just confirmed). See Release IN Documents under the inventory module. Look at its page and BLC structure. This is what we used for similar logic.

Here is an example of what I think you are trying to do?
[image]

Comment: It will be updated during execution, or after execution?

Comment: each line updates as the process is running. It might update in bulk however being maybe every 5-10-etc. records at a time depending on how much time it takes each record to process and how often the process refreshes the page. In the image you can see that some of the lines have been updated and some are still waiting to be processed (no green check or red x)